# How to change mail configuration before sending a each mail using Laravel?

Tags: email, laravel

In my application, I am sending a mail from different controller. But for that, I want to set mail configuration before sending each mail.

I know this could be done by `Config::set('key':value);`

But I do not write it in every controller, so is there any before mail send like event in Laravel.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in the config ?

Comment: i want to change mail host, port, username and password

Comment: you can have a method like sendEmail($host,$username,$password) in the Controller and in all child controller use $this->sendEmail() which will dyncamically set the host username and password from argument